# How to smooth the transition animation in VueJS

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I wish to achieve the smooth transition from one state to another, state given in image:
[image: Initial Sate]

And the final state:
[image]

Here is the temporary working Codepen:
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/psckiller/pen/JjYXoKj)

```html
 <transition name="fade">
      <h1 v-if="!searchStatus">{{heading}}</h1>
    </transition>
```

Is there any way smoothing the transition.

Comment: Link to codepen is here: 
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/psckiller/pen/JjYXoKj)

Answer (score 0):

The transitions built into Vuetify are very, very simple and not designed for the kind of choreographed animation it looks like you're trying to build. They're for things like showing or hiding an element, moving between tabs in a tab pane, etc. (i.e. animating a *single* element), and not designed to coordinate changes happening between *multiple* elements. Unfortunately, as it says in [this blog post](https://blog.gyrosco.pe/smooth-css-animations-7d8ffc2c1d29) "there is no silver bullet for great animations."

I suggest that you don't try to rely on built-in Vuetify transitions here, but instead go for a plain CSS keyframe-based strategy (here's [an old but decent introduction to the approach](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/)). Alternatively, if you'd like to use a tool built specifically for animation, [GSAP](https://greensock.com/) is about as close to an industry standard as there is, although it might be overkill for the scenario you've described.